# Syntax error when declaring a struct

Tags: c

This is my code that has a syntax error.

```
struct cell{
        bool in;
        bool up;
        bool left;
        int prevx, prevy;
};
cell MAZE[xsize][ysize];
```

This code, which looks good to me returns me on the line "cell" this error:

```
error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before 'MAZE'
```

Can any of you point out my mistake?

Comment: For consistency, shouldn't the `prevx` and `prevy` declarations be on separate lines separated by a semi-colon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this too.

```
struct cell{
        bool in;
        bool up;
        bool left;
        int prevx, prevy;
}MAZE[xsize][ysize];
```

Answer (score 10):

The correct way to declare the struct is:

```
struct cell MAZE[xsize][ysize];
```

You can also do this:

```
typedef struct {
    bool in;
    bool up;
    bool left;
    int prevx, prevy;
} cell;

cell MAZE[xsize][ysize];
```

Answer (score 2):

In C, you have to write:

```
struct cell MAZE[xsize][ysize];
```

In C++, there's an 'automatic typedef', but not in C.

You could also write:

```
typedef struct cell cell;
```

Then your declaration (not initialization) would be correct.

Usually, all-caps names such as MAZE are reserved for macros in C.